# Wired connection keeps loosing internet connection on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Tags: networking, server, 18.04, internet, ethernet

I am running Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS.

Running a ping shows that I keep loosing packets

```
ping google.com -D -O

[1554813201.789920] 64 bytes from lhr35s05-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.212.78): icmp_seq=1515 ttl=54 time=9.15 ms[1554813202.790238] 64 bytes from lhr35s05-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.212.78): icmp_seq=1516 ttl=54 time=9.17 ms
[1554813203.792015] 64 bytes from lhr35s05-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.212.78): icmp_seq=1517 ttl=54 time=9.67 ms
[1554813204.793209] 64 bytes from lhr35s05-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.212.78): icmp_seq=1518 ttl=54 time=9.10 ms
[1554813205.794539] 64 bytes from lhr35s05-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.212.78): icmp_seq=1519 ttl=54 time=9.23 ms
[1554813206.795682] 64 bytes from lhr35s05-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.212.78): icmp_seq=1520 ttl=54 time=9.07 ms
[1554813208.793010] no answer yet for icmp_seq=1521
[1554813208.802225] 64 bytes from lhr35s05-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.212.78): icmp_seq=1522 ttl=54 time=9.13 ms
[1554813210.809027] no answer yet for icmp_seq=1523
[1554813210.818212] 64 bytes from lhr35s05-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.212.78): icmp_seq=1524 ttl=54 time=9.12 ms
[1554813212.825006] no answer yet for icmp_seq=1525
[1554813213.849020] no answer yet for icmp_seq=1526
[1554813214.873033] no answer yet for icmp_seq=1527
[1554813215.897025] no answer yet for icmp_seq=1528
[1554813216.921026] no answer yet for icmp_seq=1529
[1554813217.945047] no answer yet for icmp_seq=1530
[1554813218.969034] no answer yet for icmp_seq=1531
[1554813219.993022] no answer yet for icmp_seq=1532
[1554813221.017070] no answer yet for icmp_seq=1533
[1554813222.041048] no answer yet for icmp_seq=1534
[1554813223.065043] no answer yet for icmp_seq=1535
[1554813224.089020] no answer yet for icmp_seq=1536
[1554813225.113039] no answer yet for icmp_seq=1537
[1554813226.137056] no answer yet for icmp_seq=1538
[1554813227.161056] no answer yet for icmp_seq=1539
[1554813228.185024] no answer yet for icmp_seq=1540
[1554813229.209004] no answer yet for icmp_seq=1541
[1554813230.233020] no answer yet for icmp_seq=1542
[1554813231.257036] no answer yet for icmp_seq=1543
[1554813231.266532] 64 bytes from lhr35s05-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.212.78): icmp_seq=1544 ttl=54 time=9.44 ms
[1554813232.267725] 64 bytes from lhr35s05-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.212.78): icmp_seq=1545 ttl=54 time=9.12 ms
[1554813233.268997] 64 bytes from lhr35s05-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.212.78): icmp_seq=1546 ttl=54 time=9.17 ms
[1554813234.270495] 64 bytes from lhr35s05-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.212.78): icmp_seq=1547 ttl=54 time=9.42 ms
[1554813235.272539] 64 bytes from lhr35s05-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.212.78): icmp_seq=1548 ttl=54 time=9.97 ms
[1554813236.272766] 64 bytes from lhr35s05-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.212.78): icmp_seq=1549 ttl=54 time=9.44
```

ifconfig results:

```
eno1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500        inet 192.168.50.92  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.50.255
        inet6 fe80::d267:e5ff:fee8:6ae1  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether d0:67:e5:e8:6a:e1  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 787572  bytes 65134999 (65.1 MB)
        RX errors 65744  dropped 1939  overruns 0  frame 7156
        TX packets 1032248  bytes 173826137 (173.8 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 15101
        device interrupt 16  


lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 755199  bytes 91690755 (91.6 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 755199  bytes 91690755 (91.6 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

The fact that eno1 shows RX errors and dropped im guessing is a bad thing?

I'm quite new to Ubuntu, and have been trying to dig around on this for some time now, but feel a bit blind in doing so, so hoping someone can give me some guidance on investigation and rectifying this issue.

Edit1:
I have been asked to provide some extra detail in my question:

Running:

```
dmesg | grep -i eth0
```

Gives me:

```
[    3.330821] tg3 0000:02:00.0 eth0: Tigon3 [partno(BCM95722) rev a200] (PCI Express) MAC address d0:67:e5:e8:6a:e1
[    3.330923] tg3 0000:02:00.0 eth0: attached PHY is 5722/5756 (10/100/1000Base-T Ethernet) (WireSpeed[1], EEE[0])
[    3.331021] tg3 0000:02:00.0 eth0: RXcsums[1] LinkChgREG[0] MIirq[0] ASF[1] TSOcap[1]
[    3.331115] tg3 0000:02:00.0 eth0: dma_rwctrl[76180000] dma_mask[64-bit]
[    3.335489] tg3 0000:02:00.0 eno1: renamed from eth0
```

Running:

```
dmesg | grep -i eno1
```

Gives me:

```
[    3.335489] tg3 0000:02:00.0 eno1: renamed from eth0
[   11.431508] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eno1: link is not ready
[   13.760574] tg3 0000:02:00.0 eno1: Link is up at 1000 Mbps, full duplex
[   13.760580] tg3 0000:02:00.0 eno1: Flow control is off for TX and off for RX
[   13.760592] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eno1: link becomes ready
[  223.288087] tg3 0000:02:00.0 eno1: Link is down
[  226.700240] tg3 0000:02:00.0 eno1: Link is up at 1000 Mbps, full duplex
[  226.700255] tg3 0000:02:00.0 eno1: Flow control is on for TX and on for RX
```

Running:

```
nmcli device
```

Gives me:

```
DEVICE  TYPE      STATE      CONNECTION 
eno1    ethernet  unmanaged  --         
lo      loopback  unmanaged  --
```

Running:

```
nmcli device show eno1 | grep IP4.DNS
```

Does not give me any results.

Running:

```
cat /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf | tail -3
```

Gives me:

```
nameserver 192.168.50.19
nameserver 192.168.50.20
```

These are both internal DNS services we manage ourselves.

Running:

```
ls -l /etc/resolv.conf
```

Gives me:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 39 Jul 25  2018 /etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf
```

Running:

```
cat /etc/resolv.conf | tail -4
```

Gives me:

```
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0
```

My yaml file:

```
# This file is generated from information provided by
# the datasource.  Changes to it will not persist across an instance.
# To disable cloud-init's network configuration capabilities, write a file
# /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following:
# network: {config: disabled}
network:
    version: 2
    renderer: networkd
    ethernets:
        eno1:
            addresses: [ 192.168.50.92/24 ]
            dhcp4: false
            gateway4: 192.168.50.1
            nameservers:
                addresses: [ 192.168.50.19, 192.168.50.20]
```

Yaml file with routing:

```
# This file is generated from information provided by
# the datasource.  Changes to it will not persist across an instance.
# To disable cloud-init's network configuration capabilities, write a file
# /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following:
# network: {config: disabled}
network:
    version: 2
    renderer: networkd
    ethernets:
        eno1:
            addresses: [ 192.168.50.92/24 ]
            dhcp4: false
            nameservers:
                addresses: [ 192.168.50.19, 192.168.50.20 ]
            routes:
            - to: 0.0.0.0/0
              via: 192.168.50.1
              on-link: true
```

Comment: You displayed the result after `ping lhr35s05-in-f14.1e100.net`. Is this consistent? i.e. do you receive the similar output every time? I tried to ping the same `ping lhr35s05-in-f14.1e100.net` just only once (I have Wi-Fi), but the output  was smooth and never observed the same as yours. You repeat pinging few times and change pinging IP address too.  See you get any consistent pattern of  `RX errors` or `dropped`.

Comment: The drops are not consistent, but if I ping to multiple addresses (eg: bbc.com & google.com) at the same time, they tend to drop at the same time. I know it must be something to do with the Ubuntu server, as we have multiple servers on this broadband line, and this is the only one with the issue. Any pings internal on the network to and from this server are always stable.

Comment: @Jeffery, why don't you run `traceroute lhr35s05-in-f14.1e100.net` and check for any network issues? Refer: https://linuxconfig.org/traceroute-basics

Comment: For benefit of doubt I have tried this an cannot see any issue. But to expand on what this server does, it connects to over 100 different hosts, and when the ping goes down, we see the connection to all hosts go down at the same time, half the hosts are with one hosting provider, and the other half with another hosting provider, so once again pointing to it being an issue within the Ubuntu server, as not both hosting providers, as well as google and bbc, would all be having problems at exactly the same time.

Comment: @Jeffery, please edit your question and post  output of the following commands: 1. `dmesg | grep -i eth0`, and 2. `dmesg | grep -i eno1`

Comment: I have updated the question with the output from those commands.

Comment: @Jeffery, please edit your question and post  output of the following commands: 1. `nmcli device`,  2. `nmcli device show eno1 | grep IP4.DNS`  3. `cat /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf | tail -3` and 4. `ls -l /etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: What about 4th command `ls -l /etc/resolv.conf` ? you have not posted its output! BTW, `nmcli device` output says that your Ethernet  `eno1` is NOT connected. Why? Also please post `cat /etc/resolv.conf | tail -4`

Comment: @Marmayogi Sorry missed number 4, added now. I don't know why it says it is NOT connected when it is, sorry im quite new to digging around in Ubuntu, im trying to understand the stuff your asking me to run but its only making a certain amount of sense.

Comment: We need to connect Ethernet `eno1` with some network provider.  Is it broadband? Also command `nmcli device show eno1 | grep IP4.DNS` was also failing because of want of network! The output of such commands are really needed to continue further.

Comment: There is only 1 network socket on this Server, which is plugged in and the Server currently has broadband connection. I see mentions of eno1 and eth0, could it be at some point someone has renamed it from eno1 to eth0 in the past? How do I go about sorting this out? Ubuntu should only be aware of the 1 Ethernet port thats available, no 'Virtual' ones or anything.

Comment: Please post the output of `ip addr show`. Shall move to chat session?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92267/discussion-between-jeffrey-and-marmayogi).

Comment: have you changed your LAN cable? use any other cable and check if you get same problem?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution which worked for some people so I'm sharing it to you.

1. First run

   ```
   ifconfig -a
   ```

   and the problem's always that no assigned IP from cable on eth0. Use

   ```
   sudo dhclient eth0
   ```

   and it works again, but it stops working after reboot.
2. Edit the file `/etc/network/interfaces` and change so it looks like this:

   ```
   # The loopback network interface
   auto lo
   iface lo inet loopback

   # The primary network interface
   auto eth0
   iface eth0 inet dhcp
   ```

BTW: if you have the wireless connection up, that might interfere with wired connection, you can try **wicd-network-manager** (available in Ubuntu Software Center) to configure the wireless connection.

Comment: If you check my question detail you will see that ifconfig shows there is an IP address against eno1.